# What is the solidity type for a Tx Hash?

Tags: solidity, web3js

What is the solidity type for a Tx Hash?
I am trying with address, but solidity revert errors.

I need to pass a Tx Hash as parameter in a function.
I tried with string calldata and works. The problem is that I need to index into a event.

```
event myEvent(address indexed PayHash);

function MyFunc(address PayHash) external{ 

   /*code*/
   emit myEvent(PayHash);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most (if not all) hashes in Ethereum, a transaction hash is a [bytes32](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/types.html?highlight=bytes32#fixed-size-byte-arrays).